# Place of adverb in sentences

Tags: adverbs

1) It is estimated there are between 6000 and 10000 workers in the village.

2) It is estimated there are up to 6000 workers in the village.

Would it be correct if i use “up to” and “ between” after noun ?

1) It is estimated there are workers between 6000 and 10000 in the village.

2) It is estimated there are workers up to 6000 in the village.

Comment: No it would not. Neither of the sentences you suggest is grammatically correct. Why do you wish to rewrite the first two examples?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us your goal. Why do you want to change the place? Are you trying to rephrase the whole thing? Is this something that works for you: *"It is estimated that the number of workers in the village is between 6000 and 10000"?*